# Navbar not working when clicked on mobile phone or mobile view

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a html website. On mobile phone or mobile view the website navbar is not responding

I've tried, but not working. when the navbar is clicked on mobile or mobile view, it doesn't respond and doesn't close neither. Its just stuck.

```
<!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header id="header" class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <img src="assets/img/logo.jpg" class="" alt="">
      <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">...</a></h1>
      <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
      <!-- <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt=""></a>-->
      

      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
            
        <ul>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="service.html">Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto " href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="team.html">Team</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
      </nav><!-- .navbar -->

    </div>
  </header><!-- End Header -->
```

And here is the CSS code below.

```
                /*--------------------------------------------------------------

                # Navigation Menu

                --------------------------------------------------------------*/

                /**

                * Desktop Navigation 

                */

                .navbar {

                  padding: 0;

                }



                .navbar ul {

                  margin: 0;

                  padding: 0;

                  display: flex;

                  list-style: none;

                  align-items: center;

                }



                .navbar li {

                  position: relative;

                }



                .navbar>ul>li {

                  white-space: nowrap;

                  padding: 10px 0 10px 28px;

                }



                .navbar a,

                .navbar a:focus {

                  display: flex;

                  align-items: center;

                  justify-content: space-between;

                  padding: 0 3px;

                  font-size: 15px;

                  font-weight: 600;

                  color: #222222;

                  white-space: nowrap;

                  transition: 0.3s;

                  position: relative;

                }



                .navbar a i,

                .navbar a:focus i {

                  font-size: 12px;

                  line-height: 0;

                  margin-left: 5px;

                }



                .navbar>ul>li>a:before {

                  content: "";

                  position: absolute;

                  width: 100%;

                  height: 2px;

                  bottom: -6px;

                  left: 0;

                  background-color: #106eea;

                  visibility: hidden;

                  width: 0px;

                  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;

                }



                .navbar a:hover:before,

                .navbar li:hover>a:before,

                .navbar .active:before {

                  visibility: visible;

                  width: 100%;

                }



                .navbar a:hover,

                .navbar .active,

                .navbar .active:focus,

                .navbar li:hover>a {

                  color: #106eea;

               
 }
.navbar .dropdown ul {
                  display: block;
                  position: absolute;
                  left: 28px;
                  top: calc(100% + 30px);
                  margin: 0;
                  padding: 10px 0;
                  z-index: 99;
                  opacity: 0;
                  visibility: hidden;
                  background: #fff;
                  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
                  transition: 0.3s;
                }

                .navbar .dropdown ul li {
                  min-width: 200px;
                }

                .navbar .dropdown ul a {
                  padding: 10px 20px;
                  font-weight: 400;
                }

                .navbar .dropdown ul a i {
                  font-size: 12px;
                }

                .navbar .dropdown ul a:hover,
                .navbar .dropdown ul .active:hover,
                .navbar .dropdown ul li:hover>a {
                  color: #106eea;
                }

                .navbar .dropdown:hover>ul {
                  opacity: 1;
                  top: 100%;
                  visibility: visible;
                }

                .navbar .dropdown .dropdown ul {
                  top: 0;
                  left: calc(100% - 30px);
                  visibility: hidden;
                }

                .navbar .dropdown .dropdown:hover>ul {
                  opacity: 1;
                  top: 0;
                  left: 100%;
                  visibility: visible;
                }

                @media (max-width: 1366px) {
                  .navbar .dropdown .dropdown ul {
                    left: -90%;
                  }

                  .navbar .dropdown .dropdown:hover>ul {
                    left: -100%;
                  }
                }
.mobile-nav-toggle {
                  color: #222222;
                  font-size: 28px;
                  cursor: pointer;
                  display: none;
                  line-height: 0;
                  transition: 0.5s;
                }

                .mobile-nav-toggle.bi-x {
                  color: #fff;
                }

                @media (max-width: 991px) {
                  .mobile-nav-toggle {
                    display: block;
                  }

                  .navbar ul {
                    display: none;
                  }
                }

                .navbar-mobile {
                  position: fixed;
                  overflow: hidden;
                  top: 0;
                  right: 0;
                  left: 0;
                  bottom: 0;
                  background: rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.9);
                  transition: 0.3s;
                  z-index: 999;
                }

                .navbar-mobile .mobile-nav-toggle {
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 15px;
                  right: 15px;
                }

                .navbar-mobile ul {
                  display: block;
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 55px;
                  right: 15px;
                  bottom: 15px;
                  left: 15px;
                  padding: 10px 0;
                  background-color: #fff;
                  overflow-y: auto;
                  transition: 0.3s;
                }

                .navbar-mobile a,
                .navbar-mobile a:focus {
                  padding: 10px 20px;
                  font-size: 15px;
                  color: #222222;
                }

                .navbar-mobile>ul>li {
                  padding: 0;
                }

                .navbar-mobile a:hover:before,
                .navbar-mobile li:hover>a:before,
                .navbar-mobile .active:before {
                  visibility: hidden;
                }

                .navbar-mobile a:hover,
                .navbar-mobile .active,
                .navbar-mobile li:hover>a {
                  color: #106eea;
                }

                .navbar-mobile .getstarted,
                .navbar-mobile .getstarted:focus {
                  margin: 15px;
                }

                .navbar-mobile .dropdown ul {
                  position: static;
                  display: none;
                  margin: 10px 20px;
                  padding: 10px 0;
                  z-index: 99;
                  opacity: 1;
                  visibility: visible;
                  background: #fff;
                  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
                }

                .navbar-mobile .dropdown ul li {
                  min-width: 200px;
                }

                .navbar-mobile .dropdown ul a {
                  padding: 10px 20px;
                }

                .navbar-mobile .dropdown ul a i {
                  font-size: 12px;
                }

                .navbar-mobile .dropdown ul a:hover,
                .navbar-mobile .dropdown ul .active:hover,
                .navbar-mobile .dropdown ul li:hover>a {
                  color: #106eea;
                }

                .navbar-mobile .dropdown>.dropdown-active {
                  display: block;
                }
```

I want navbar to open (respond better) when clicked, and also close when clicked again. Please what can be done, i'm completely lost. Below is the code.

Answer (score 0):

I removed some code and added clickable functionality for the menu toggling. I just changed the toggle icon for the mobile view; if you change yours, then replace it with your own. I hope this code is useful for you.

```js
$('.toggle-icon').on('click', function() {
    $('.navbar').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.navbar {
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar>ul>li {
    padding: 10px 14px;
}

.navbar a,
.navbar a:focus {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #222222;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: 0.3s;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar>ul>li>a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: -6px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #106eea;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar a:hover:before,
.navbar li:hover>a:before,
.navbar .active:before {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.navbar .active,
.navbar .active:focus,
.navbar li:hover>a {
    color: #106eea;
}

.toggle-icon {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .toggle-icon {
        display: block;
    }

    header .navbar {
        display: none;
    }

    header .navbar.active {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .navbar.active {
        background: #ccc;
    }

    .navbar.active ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .navbar>ul>li {
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-jnSuA4Ss2PkkikSOLtYs8BlYIeeIK1h99ty4YfvRPAlzr377vr3CXDb7sb7eEEBYjDtcYj+AjBH3FLv5uSJuXg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<header id="header" class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <img src="assets/img/logo.jpg" class="" alt="">
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">...</a></h1>
        <div class="toggle-icon">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5m0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5m0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar" >
            <ul>
                <li><a class="nav-link scrollto active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="service.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link scrollto " href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="team.html">Team</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Yes, worked. Thanks again